# How to break random elements in doubly linkedList

Tags: java, linked-list

hello i am trying to generate a random doubly linkedlist but i have to insert the node with a negative value and its next node(value doesnt matter) to the HEAD of the list but when i compile the program i am stuck in an infinite loop with one repeating number.I think i connected the list wrong but i am not sure. For context LC is the NODE class, tete is head queue is tail, prev and suiv and next and previous pointer.

```
class LC {
    public int data;
    public LC suiv;
    public LC prec;
}


    public class ChainesDouble {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        //Détermine an even number N between 10 and 30

        int N = (int)(Math.random()*16)+5;
        N = (N*2);
        System.out.println("La valeur de N = " + N);
        // Create a doubly linkedlist with N elements
        LC tete = null;
        LC queue = null;
        for (int i = 0; i < N/2; i++) {
            int valeur = getRandom();
            int next = getRandom();
            //If the generated number is negative insert that number and              
            //next value into the head of the list
            if(valeur <0) {
                LC temp = new LC();
                temp.data = valeur;
                if(tete == null) {
                    queue = temp;
                }
                temp = new LC();
                temp.data = next ;
                tete.prec = temp ;
                temp.suiv = tete ;
                tete = temp ;
                tete.prec = temp ;
                temp.suiv = tete ;
                tete = temp ;
            
                

                //If the number is positive, insert the element and the
                //next element  into the TAIL of the list

            }
            else {
                LC temp = new LC();
                temp.data = valeur;
                if(queue == null) {
                    tete = temp;
                    queue = temp;

                }else {
                    temp.prec = queue;
                    queue.suiv = temp ;
                    queue = temp ;
                }
                temp.prec = queue;
                queue.suiv = temp ;
                queue = temp ;
            }           
        }
       public static int getRandom(){
        int N = (int)(Math.random()*42);
        if(N<21) {
            N -=30;//Rand(-10;-30)
        }
        else {
            N-=11;//Rand(10;30)

        }
        return N;
    }
}
```

Comment: Please do provide complete snippet. Your one is not even compilable because of there're no two closed `}`. What is implementation of `LC`?

Comment: @oleg.cherednik i have just edited the snippet. Sorry about that

Comment: `getRnadom()` implementation?

Comment: I have added that @oleg.cherednik

Comment: Your text would be much more readable if you would capitalize the first letter of each sentence.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if i got your requirements correctly. But here is a loop that would achieve a doubly linked list with your tete and queue. The comments explain the logic.

```
class LC {
   public int data;
   public LC suiv;
   public LC prec;
}

public class ChainesDouble {
public static int getRandom(){      
    int N = (int)(Math.random()*42);        
    if(N<21) {          
        N -=30;
    }       else {          
        N-=11;          
    }       
    return N;   
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    int N = (int)(Math.random()*16)+5;
    N = (N*2);
    System.out.println("La valeur de N = " + N);

    LC tete = null;
    LC queue = null;
    for (int i = 0; i < N/2; i++) {
        int valeur = getRandom();
        int next = getRandom();
        
        //get the two random values
        LC temp_a = new LC();
        LC temp_b = new LC();
        
        //Store the data in the two nodes
        temp_a.data = valeur;
        temp_b.data = next ;  
        
        //link the two nodes
        temp_a.suiv = temp_b;
        temp_b.prec = temp_a;
        
        //If the list is empty, then initialize tete(head) and queue(tail)
        if(tete == null) {
            tete = temp_a;
            queue = temp_b;
        } else {
            
            if(valeur <0) { //If valeur is negative, add to tete
                    temp_b.suiv = tete;
                    tete.prec = temp_b;
                    tete = temp_a;
            }
            else { //If valeur is positive, add to queue
                   queue.suiv = temp_a;           
                   temp_a.prec =  queue;
                   queue = temp_b;
            }
        }
        
    }
    
    //Test Program
    LC temp = tete;
    while (temp!=null) {
        System.out.println(temp.data);
        temp=temp.suiv;
    }

    //Search for second multiple of 5
    LC search = tete;
    int count = 0;
    boolean found = false;
    while (search!=null) {
        if (search.data%5==0)
            count++;
        if (count==2) {
            found = true;
            System.out.println("Found "+search.data);
            break;
        }
        search = search.suiv;
    }
    
    //if found
    if (found) {
        int position = 5;
        if (search.data%10==0) position = 10;
        System.out.println("Position "+position);
        
       //remove search for current position
        if (search.suiv!=null) {
            LC prev = search.prec;
            LC next = search.suiv;
            prev.suiv = next;
            next.prec = prev;
        } else {
            search.prec.suiv = null;
        }
        
        //move pointer to desired position
        LC move = tete;
        int cur = 1;
        while(move!=null) {
            move = move.suiv;
            cur++;
            if (cur==(position - 1)) {
                break;
            }
        }
        System.out.println("shifting "+search.data+" to after "+move.data);
        //link searched item into desired position

            search.suiv = move.suiv;
            move.suiv.prec = search;
            move.suiv = search;
            search.prec = move;

        
    }
 }
 }
```

Comment: I just used your method and it works but it is not printing out the whole list of N elements

Comment: @QuangCao, I tested it and it worked fine. How many elements did it show and what were you expecting?

Comment: well for exmple when it says N=10 it only prints out 3 elements and sometimes it throws a nullpointer exception

Comment: Let me paste the entire program

Comment: it could be because of other parts of my program but i cant post the whole thing here its too long haha @Kasalwe

Comment: I have pasted the entire program. You can test it and give feedback.

Comment: i have tested it and it works fine. I guess its other parts of my program that is now acting up. If you can may i ask you to take a look at the full program with me?

Comment: Sure. Lets have a look

Comment: may i have your email address? i will send you the full code

Comment: Lets chat https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/220173/code-test

Comment: i dont have 20 reputation so i cannot use chat room..

Comment: Sorry, i didn't know that limitation. https://codeshare.io/248mJL

Comment: heres the link with updated english comments for u to understand https://codeshare.io/248mJL

Comment: You are using some languages i dont understand. In short, after generating the list, what are you supposed to do?

Comment: i am using java. basically after the list i have to search the list for the 2nd occurance of a multiple of 5(5,10,15etc) and detatch that node and reattatch it in the 5th node of the list or the 10th node if it is divisible by 10. you can see it in the LC e9 as the node i have to connect to

Comment: I think the logic is the one crashing the program. Meaning if the first item is 30 and the second 30, then you need to shift to the 30th node (Which does not exist)?

Comment: No for example if it is 30 and 30 then the second 30 will be shifted to the 10th node cause it is divisible by 10

Comment: @QuangCao. Check the updated code. It does what you indicated. Please remember to accept my answer if you are sastisfied.

Comment: can you resend the link as mine only shows my old code

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Random random = new Random();
    int halfSize = random.nextInt(30) + 1;
    ListNode head = createLinkedList(halfSize, random);
    System.out.println(printToString(head));
}

private static String printToString(ListNode node) {
    StringBuilder buf = new StringBuilder();

    while (node != null) {
        if (buf.length() > 0)
            buf.append("->");
        buf.append(node.value);
        node = node.next;
    }

    return buf.toString();
}

public static ListNode createLinkedList(int halfSize, Random random) {
    ListNode head = null;
    ListNode tail = null;

    for (int i = 0; i < halfSize; i++) {
        int one = getRandomValue(random);
        int two = getRandomValue(random);

        if (one >= 0) {
            tail = addTail(one, tail);
            head = head == null ? tail : head;
            tail = addTail(two, tail);
        } else {
            head = addHead(one, head);
            head = addHead(two, head);
        }
    }

    return head;
}

private static ListNode addHead(int value, ListNode head) {
    ListNode node = new ListNode(value);
    node.next = head;

    if (head != null)
        head.prev = node;

    return node;
}

private static ListNode addTail(int value, ListNode tail) {
    ListNode node = new ListNode(value);
    node.prev = tail;

    if (tail != null)
        tail.next = node;

    return node;
}

private static int getRandomValue(Random random) {
    return (random.nextInt(30) + 1) * (random.nextBoolean() ? 1 : -1);
}

public static final class ListNode {

    public final int value;
    public ListNode next;
    public ListNode prev;

    public ListNode(int value) {
        this.value = value;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return String.valueOf(value);
    }
}
```